# Moq - Accessing the mocked object's properties

Tags: moq

Eg:
I have an interface with a property and a method.
The method does something with the value of the property.
How do I setup the mock to access the value of property?

```
interface myInterface
{
    Id{get;set;}
    string ReturnIdAsString();
}

Mock<myInterface> mock = new Mock<myInterface>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Id).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(m => m.ReturnsIdAsString).Returns(**would like to return m.Id here**);

mock.Object.ReturnsIdAsString(); //should return the value in m.Id
```

How do I setup ReturnsIdAsString to access the property Id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `SetupGet` for properties. Since you're mocking an interface, there won't be any underlying implementation, and you'll have to set up the method too.

```
Mock<myInterface> mock = new Mock<myInterface>(){CallBase = true};
mock.SetupGet(m => m.Id).Returns(1);
mock.Setup(m => m.ReturnsIdAsString()).Returns("1");
```

You could alternatively make the method use a lambda on its return, if you're intending to change the return value of the `Id` property.

```
mock.Setup(m => m.ReturnsIdAsString()).Returns(() => mock.Object.Id.ToString());
```

Remember that even if your class calls `m.Id = 42` it won't change the `Get` of the property, though you can verify a `Set`.

```
mock.VerifySet(m => m.Id = 42);
```

Comment: Haha, you're right, both options in my answer are completely wrong.